# How to pass in options for user to FormBuilder form?

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to create a new FormBuilder form using the Bot Framework and for one of my fields I need to validate that the option entered matches some user specific options. How would I pass the user specific options to validate these?

Thank you! This is how I'm building my form:

```
    internal static IDialog<Form> CreateFormDialog()
    {
        return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(Form.BuildForm));
    }

    // Called when a user interacts with the bot through slack
    public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, CreateFormDialog);
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the FormDialog.FromForm, you can create the FormDialog with the new keyword and pass the options to the form state.

```
var myForm = new FormDialog<MyFormState>(new MyFormState(options), Form.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart);
```